# How to save all related data using django signals post_save

Tags: django

I just want that if the admin insert the Course(ABM) and Education Level (Grade 11) and Section(Chronicles) it will get all related data in subjectsectionteacher(second picture) and it will automatic save to student enrolled subject(third picture) my problem is only one data save.

[image]

[image: subjectsectionteacher]
[image]

this is my code in models.py

```
class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
    Student_Users = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, related_name='students', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Section = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Payment_Type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)

class SubjectSectionTeacher(models.Model):
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Sections = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Subjects = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Employee_Users = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class StudentsEnrolledSubject(models.Model):
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+',
                                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Subject_Section_Teacher = models.ForeignKey(SubjectSectionTeacher, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                null=True,blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
    def create(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        teachers = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.all().filter(Sections=instance.Section,Education_Levels=instance.Education_Levels)
        if created and teachers.exists():
            StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.update_or_create(
                # This should be the instance not instance.Student_Users
                Students_Enrollment_Records=instance,
                # The below is also not an instance of SubjectSectionTeacher
                Subject_Section_Teacher=teachers.first())
```

I hope the title and the picture is enough to understand what im trying to say if not, im sorry!

**UPDATE** 
this what i want

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
for each in teachers:
            if created and teachers.exists():
                StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.create(
                        pk=each.id,
                        Students_Enrollment_Records=instance,
                        Subject_Section_Teacher=each

                    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `save()` method on the models to update the related data.

within the model class, you should define a method as

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #Code here
    if self.courses = "ABM":
        self.x = Model2.objects.get(id=x) #Whatever code you want
    super(model_name, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: wouldn't that be too easy ;)